How to ensure that a Debian package's docs are actually installed as part of the package?
I'm using Debian's "dh_installdocs" feature to include docs as part of my package. The rules file looks roughly like this:
...
binary-arch: build install
    dh_testdir
    dh_testroot
    dh_installchangelogs
    dh_installdocs
    dh_installexamples
    ...

binary: binary-indep binary-arch

The .docs file looks like this:
LICENSE-Community.txt
README
THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES
MPL-2
sbom_from_silk.json

I build my .deb file, and confirm that the aforementioned docs files are indeed in the /usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/ directory (using dpkg-deb -c):
dpkg-deb -c repo/apt/debian/dists/bookworm/mongodb-org/7.0/main/binary-amd64/mongodb-org-server_7.0.11\~patch\~664f90edeaa2ee0007556712_amd64.deb 
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./etc/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       578 2013-12-19 05:41 ./etc/mongod.conf
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./lib/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./lib/systemd/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./lib/systemd/system/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       787 2013-12-19 05:41 ./lib/systemd/system/mongod.service
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/bin/
-rwxr-xr-x root/root 182774512 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/bin/mongod
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/doc/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/
-rw-r--r-- root/root     10435 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/LICENSE-Community.txt.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      5311 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/MPL-2.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root      1978 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/README
-rw-r--r-- root/root     18316 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/THIRD-PARTY-NOTICES.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       363 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/changelog.gz
-rw-r--r-- root/root       492 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/copyright
-rw-r--r-- root/root        23 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/sbom_from_silk.json
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/lintian/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/lintian/overrides/
-rw-r--r-- root/root       454 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/lintian/overrides/mongodb-org-server
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/man/
drwxr-xr-x root/root         0 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/man/man1/
-rw-r--r-- root/root     27397 2013-12-19 05:41 ./usr/share/man/man1/mongod.1.gz

However, when I install the package (via apt-get), it appears that the /usr/share/doc/mongodb-org-server/* files are not placed anywhere on my system.
Is this intended behavior? I'm hoping that there's some configuration setting I'm misunderstanding about how docs files are packaged & installed.
